# android Uri to Java URI

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

I need a quick help on how to convert android Uri to Java URI. My requirement is to capture images and store them in External storage. To pass these images across activities, I decided to use an Arraylist that holds Uris of images and pass on this arraylist as an intent-extra to next activity. But, Arraylist accepts only JavaURI.

```
String image = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
File photo=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),image);
selectedImageA=Uri.fromFile(photo);
imageIndex++;
selectedImageJ= <Looking for code here>;
imagesUriArray.add(imageIndex,selectedImageJ);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ScanActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is a generic implementation of `List`. Can you show us where you declare `imagesUriArray`?

Comment: ArrayList<Uri> imagesUriArray. I found a way and It is working fine for me. Thankyou for your quick response @E_net4

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imagesUriArray = new ArrayList<Uri>;
```

If this doesn't work, declare your `ArrayList` as `String list` and convert the `uri` to `String`. And later, initialize the `uri` from the `Uri` string

Comment: Thank you for your response. As @E_net4 pointed, Arraylist is generic and i later found a way to accommodate Android Uri in ArrayList without converting it to JavaURI.